# Plotting solution of complex equation with parameters with Python

Tags: python, numpy

This sounds to be something well explored, so I just need a reference.

I need to take a look (i.e. sketch the plot) to the solution of certain complex equations with several complex parameters and I would like to do that using Python/NumPy.
I have a certain number of complex functions of one complex variable depending on two parameters, and I need to add and compose them and finally to study the set of complex numbers such that the modulus of the above sum and composition is equal to a fixed positive real number.

For short: I have to plot the graph of the solutions of a certain complex equation, and see how does it move when parameters are touched.

Can somebody give a reference, please?
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you use COLAB since it is a free and easy way to get going and has NumPy and Matplotlib availble for plotting. There is a tutorial on plotting written in Colab that you might be able to modify to suit your needs. Then come back here if you have a more specific question.  Tutorial:  https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb

Comment: Take a look at the "Interactive Plot" section of this article: [https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-dynamic-visualization-with-python-animations-and-interactive-plots-f72a7fb69245](https://towardsdatascience.com/intro-to-dynamic-visualization-with-python-animations-and-interactive-plots-f72a7fb69245)

Comment: Thanks to both. The main problem I'm having now is that I can find some code like if x and y stay in this range then the function gives back these values, but I need "the other way": to get the picture of the numbers z solving a certain equation f(z)=0.

Comment: The starting point is to plot the solutions of |1/z-1|-2=0 in the complex plane, for example. This is a circle, but after that I will have to build something more involved, composing functions and adding parameters.